# Getting Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values... But there aren't any missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had this working, and now I changed "something" and it doesn't work any more. I have a table in Excel that I'm reading into a df. That works as expected. I read it in, and then I filter it so I only have the rows of data that match a specific criteria. Here's the code:

```py
    df = excel_range_upper_left.options(pd.DataFrame, expand='table', header=1,
            index=False).value

    print(f'Check for missings')
    for c in df.columns:
        count = df[c].isnull().sum()
        print(f'Col {c} has {count} missing values')
    print(f'Done checking for missings')

    df = df[df["Phase"].str.contains('2')]  #, na=False)]
```

The for loop cycles through the df columns looking for missing values. They all come back as 0 missing values.

Then I execute the last statement, which should (I think) simply filter the df into a new df (of the same name) that has to have a string value '2' in the 'Phase' column. And that where it errors out with the `Cannot mask...` error.

My guess is that there is still a missing value somewhere in the table, but I've exhausted my ability to find it (I also tried the following - but it results in the same thing as the original df and still errors out:

```py
    print(f'{exer_df.dropna(axis=1)}')
```

If I change the filter line to the following so it includes the `na=False` option, everything works. But I don't know why...

```py
exer_df = exer_df[exer_df["Phase"].str.contains('2', na=False)]
```

Anyone have any insight and help?

For completeness, here are the results from the for loop and then the error:

```
Check for missings
Col Type as 0 missing values
Col Sub-Type as 0 missing values
Col Phase as 0 missing values
Col Body Parts as 0 missing values
Col Sets as 0 missing values
Col Reps as 0 missing values
Col Tempo as 0 missing values
Col Intensity as 0 missing values
Col Rest Period as 0 missing values
Col Exercise as 0 missing values
Col Prim Mover as 0 missing values
Done checking for miossings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/kirby/OneDrive/Beating Old Age Book/Blog Page Text/nutrition/calculations/plan_creator.py", line 271, in <module>
    mcp()
  File "c:/Users/kirby/OneDrive/Beating Old Age Book/Blog Page Text/nutrition/calculations/plan_creator.py", line 188, in mcp
    exer_df = exer_df[exer_df["Phase"].str.contains('2')]  #, na=False)]
  File "C:\Users\kirby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3014, in __getitem__
    if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
  File "C:\Users\kirby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 114, in is_bool_indexer
    raise ValueError(na_msg)
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the outcome of the below code?
`df["Phase"].isna().sum()`

Comment: It comes back with a zero for each columns, which is the perplexing part. I did find a "["  in a column - but that shouldn't be a NaN (the column has strings in it). EDIT: Give me a minute - I used `.isnull()` instead. I'll re-run with `.isna`

Comment: @ashkangh - I get the same result in that all cols come back with a zero...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in your first line of coding?
`df = excel_range_upper_left.options(pd.DataFrame, expand='table', header=1,index=False).value`

Comment: @ashkangh - this gets the data from Excel and puts it into a dataframe. It's done with xlwings. That works fine - I can iterate over the columns, find indeces, and basically manipulate the df. The problem comes when I try to apply the `.str.contains` instruction. While the `na=False` directive works, I'd really like to understand what's throwing the error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So, are you sure that the `type(df)` is a dataframe? because I'm a little skeptical about `.value` at the end of first line of your code!

Comment: Understood - here's the link to the xlwings paragraph that describes this. xlwings uses what they call `converters` to convert whatever is on the spreadsheet to whatever you need - in this case, a dataframe. My guess is that the `.value` at the end simply pulls the values from the range. in the statement under question, `excel_range_upper_left` is the Excel range for the upper left cell of the data. I can also use about any other df maniupulator on the df, so I'm sure it's a df https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-dataframe-converter

Answer (score 28):

As the original poster already stated, with the parameter `na=False` everything should be working fine.

If you try to use `Series.str.contains` in imported Excel DataFrames with blank values a ValueError raises: "*Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values*"

Specifying `na` to be `False` (`na=False`), replaces NaN values with False values and avoids this error; an alternative solution would also be `Series.fillna(False)` before calling the function.

Somehow using other filling values does not work in this particular scenario, it needs to be a Bool.

Answer (score 7):

I just got out of something similar (the very same text of the error) by doing this:

```
df.dropna()[df.dropna()['Label'].str.contains('target')]
```

So the moral may be that you'll need to drop NaNs inside your brackets, too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason why this error may occur. I was attempting to do:

```
df.loc[df['id'].str.isnumeric()]
```

The problem was that the ID had a mix of strings and integers so my fix was

```
df.loc[df['id'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()]
```